# replacing the nth character in a string only if it is a particular character in R

Tags: r, regex, string, tidyr

I am importing a series of surveys as .csv files and combining into one data set. The problem is for one of the seven files some of the variables are importing slightly differently. The data set is huge and I would like to find a way to write a function to run over dataset that is giving me trouble.

In some of the variables there is an underscore when there should be a dot. Not all variables are of the same format but the ones that are incorrect are, in that the underscore is always the 6th element of the column name.

I want R to look for the 6th element and if it is an underscore replace it with a dot. here is a made up example below.

```
col_names <- c("s1.help_needed",
               "s1.Q2_im_stuck",
               "s1.Q2.im_stuck",
               "s1.Q3.regex",
               "s1.Q3_regex",
               "s2.Q1.is_confusing",
               "s2.Q2.answer_please",
               "s2.Q2_answer_please",
               "s2.someone_knows_the answer",
               "s3.appreciate_the_help")
```

I assume there is a Regex answer to this but i am struggling to find one. perhaps there is also a tidyr answer?

Comment: None of your examples have an underscore in the 5th character as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes they do, scroll to the left, e.g. `s1.Q3_regex`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - that's the 6th character

Comment: @thelatemail Good catch, and I didn't even count, my eye caught those underscores and then I rushed to answer.  I think this is what the OP actually wants though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @thelatemail pointed out, none of your data actually has underscores in the fifth position, but some have it in the sixth position (where others have dot).  A base R approach would be to use `gsub()`:

```
result <- gsub("^(.{5})_", "\\1.", col_names)

> result
 [1] "s1.help_needed"              "s1.Q2.im_stuck"             
 [3] "s1.Q2.im_stuck"              "s1.Q3.regex"                
 [5] "s1.Q3.regex"                 "s2.Q1.is_confusing"         
 [7] "s2.Q2.answer_please"         "s2.Q2.answer_please"        
 [9] "s2.someone_knows_the answer" "s3.appreciate_the_help"
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
^         from the start of the string
(.{5})    match AND capture any five characters
_         followed by an underscore
```

The quantity in parentheses is called a *capture* group and can be used in the replacement via `\\1`.  So the regex is saying replace the first six characters with the five characters we captured but use a dot as the sixth character.

Comment: is there any need for the `sapply`, doesn't `gsub("^(.{5})_", "\\1\\.", col_names)` just work?

Comment: @SymbolixAU I didn't know this was possible with `gsub()`.

Comment: and I don't think you need to escape the `.` : `gsub("^(.{5})_", "\\1.", col_names)`

Comment: Don't need to use `gsub`. Since only one replacement is needed would be safer to use `sub` although the caret does make this answer unambiguous..

Comment: Great thanks and good spotting. @TimBiegeleisen could you please explain the syntax of the expression you used?

Comment: @JoshVanVianen I gave an explanation.

Comment: Since the dataset is apparently huge, I tried with `rep(col_names, 1e6)` and with and without `perl = TRUE`.  Medians were 2.34 seconds with and 4.46 without.

Comment: @Jota -  an ugly `substr(col_names,6,6) <- substr(chartr("_",".",col_names),6,6)` is pretty competitive speedwise, but unfortunately not very concise

Answer (score 4):

You can use a "capture-class" defined by the first 4 (actually 5) characters of any sort followed by an underscore and replace with whatever those 5 characters were was followed a "dot". Since all the examples had the underscore in the 6th position, I'm guessing you were not counting the original "dots":

```
> col_names
 [1] "s1.help_needed"              "s1.Q2_im_stuck"             
 [3] "s1.Q2.im_stuck"              "s1.Q3.regex"                
 [5] "s1.Q3_regex"                 "s2.Q1.is_confusing"         
 [7] "s2.Q2.answer_please"         "s2.Q2_answer_please"        
 [9] "s2.someone_knows_the answer" "s3.appreciate_the_help"     
> sub("^(.....)_", "\\1.", col_names)
 [1] "s1.help.needed"              "s1.Q2.im_stuck"             
 [3] "s1.Q2.im.stuck"              "s1.Q3.regex"                
 [5] "s1.Q3.regex"                 "s2.Q1.is.confusing"         
 [7] "s2.Q2.answer.please"         "s2.Q2.answer_please"        
 [9] "s2.someone.knows_the answer" "s3.appreciate.the_help"
```

Since the replacement argument does not have the same issues with escapes, you do not need to use the doubled backslashes as you might have used in an R-regex pattern argument.